# how to change the color of different files in ls

Tags: bash, colors

So I know that There is a way to change the color of text for directories, regular files, bash scripts, etc. Is there a way to change the color to the file based on the *file **extention*** name?

Ex: 

foo.txt  [is red]

foo.text  [is blue]

foo.secret  [is green]

foo.txt  [is red]

Comment: Move your question to unix.stackexchange.com if you want to get an answer

Comment: If there is, you do so by configuring `ls`, not the shell.

Comment: `eval "$(dircolors -b)"` is what Ubuntu stick in their default .bashrc https://gist.github.com/marioBonales/1637696

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: put the question over here... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322029/how-to-change-the-color-of-different-files-in-ls

Answer (score 0):

Try `zsh`, the easiest way to get:

- Colors that you want
- Shared History
- Better tab compeletion
- Git view enhancements
- ...